# Is there any symmetric key cipher (block or stream cipher) providing partial decryption?

Tags: encryption

[image]symmetric key cipher (block or stream cipher) providing partial decryption of data at some points. Although the entire data has not been decrypted, the data decrypted to that specific point should be viewed or accessed.

The partial decryption keys can be inherited form the main symmetric key to do partial decryptions successfully.

Can anyone refer to me any good stuff or papers worked out in this area?

Comment: This won't allow streaming in the forward direction, but you could use a [forward-secur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator#Definitions)e s[tream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher). ​ ​

Comment: I actually remember reading something like this, specifically in regards to compressed video, the least significant bits of quantized data were encrypted so a key was required to unlock the quality

Comment: I dont even want live-streaming ... but of-course the streaming of video upto the point which is supported by the key.  Is there any stream or block cipher whose decryption key inherits keys which can be used for partially decrypting data from specific point to point along the length of data? but with the condition that partially decrypted data can effectively be viewed like in case of video...

Comment: Would it be suitable for you to do: $E_{K_1}(K_{S_1})||E_{K_2}(K_{S_1})||E_{K_3}(K_{S_1})||E_{K_{S_1}}(DATA)$ with appropriate choices of omitting the prepended encryptions of $K_{S_1}$ for the specific parts?

Comment: @  SEJPM , Ricky Demer I have added a new more refined post what I want to have. the link is...http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35084/symmetric-cipher-providing-full-and-partial-decryption

Comment: Please edit your question to provide updates, rather than posting a new question.

Comment: Looks like the question this was closed as a duplicate of has since been automatically deleted. Since this question looks on-topic and answerable, I have voted to reopen it.